# How can I render my data in ASP.NET with foreach?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET and I learning ASP.NET with video from Udemy
Here's my code

Customer.cs (Model)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


namespace Vidly.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CustomersController.cs (Controller)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Vidly.Models;

namespace Vidly.Controllers
{
    public class CustomersController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Customers/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var customers = new List<Customer>
            {
                new Customer {Name = "Mahdi" },
                new Customer {Name = "Yaser" },
                new Customer {Name = "Zahra" },
                new Customer {Name = "Amir"  },
            };
            return View(customers);
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml (View)

```
@model Vidly.Models.Customer
<h3>Customer page</h3>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-­‐bordered">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var customer in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#"> @customer.Name </a></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

visual studio tells me problem is my `@foreach` but I don't know how to fix it! 
Thanks for helping ;)

Comment: Your `@model` is `IEnumerable<Vidly.Models.Customer>`

Comment: (var customer in Model.customer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `index.cshtml`, check your model.
You have to replace it with :

```
@model List<Vidly.Models.Customer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

`@model Vidly.Models.Customer`

To

`@model IEnumerable<Vidly.Models.Customer>`